# Regular Expression help to find letter in XML number field

Tags: regex, xml

I am getting an error importing an XML file into a custom program. Other files import correctly. However, one file produces an error from a float field. I am using Notepad++ search function with Regular Expression to try and find the issue in the XML file.

When I use `<milepost>([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)</milepost>` I get around 30,000 results which is the correct number of records but the field is supposed to be `DOUBLE`. When I use `<milepost>([0-9.]+)</milepost>` I only get 29,994 records. This tells me that the import is most likely failing because there are letters in my number fields.

I have tried a number of variations like:

```
<milepost>([\S\D\d]+)</milepost>
<milepost>(.*?)</milepost>
<milepost>([\Sa-zA-Z]+)</milepost>
<milepost>([0-9.\w]+)</milepost>
```

etc.
Each of these returns the expected 30,000 records.

When I try to search for letters using :

```
<milepost>([a-zA-Z.]*)</milepost>
<milepost>([a-zA-Z]+)</milepost>
<milepost>(^[a-zA-Z]+$)</milepost>
<milepost>([a-zA-Z.a-zA-Z]+)</milepost>
```

I get 0 results (most likely because it excludes numbers)

I did manage to find one of the records I am looking for using this method:

```
<milepost>173.811818181818a</milepost>
```

But I do not feel like scrolling through 30,000+ lines to look for 5 more records with a letter in them.

Is there a regular expression that will return to me ONLY the values that have a letter/letters in them while allowing numbers? (Fields with only numbers and a period should be excluded)

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to follow. Can you show a sample of 10 lines and point out things which should match and things which should not?

Comment: [You can't parse X|HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1422451)

Comment: @Parfait That's not particularly helpful. You can fairly successfully search a well-formed XML document using Regex if you are willing to accept that you may not catch all edge cases.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I do understand that you can not parse through XML with RegEx, it was the only thing I could think of to find my errors. I literally have 200 miles of Lat/Long coords in XML along a specific track with mileposts. Monkey is correct in that something may be missed, While the answer below was exactly what I was looking for, my file still errors so it's back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 6 problem records presumably contain a mixture of letters and numbers, but your searches for records containing letters will only match records consisting exclusively of letters.

Try

```
<milepost>.*[a-zA-Z].*</milepost>
```

which matches any record containing an ASCII letter in its value, as well as allowing other characters such as digits.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a negative look-ahead. Something like

```
<milepost>(?![0-9.]+</milepost>)
```

should be very close.

In plain English `<milepost>` not followed by exclusively digits and dots and a closing `</milepost>`